# SSRS Pie chart series labels getting cut off

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I am using SQL Server 2012
Visual Studio 2010

I have made a report with a pie chart. I want the series data labels outside the chart as you see in the images below. However the label value ClassificationMemberName is getting cut off at the top and bottom when I run the report.

As you see below for example, International Funds is getting trimmed at the top and bottom as are several of the other labels. You can't see the entire letter.

[image: chart1]

In design mode I see no way to resize the series labels through the GUI. I experimented extensively with various properties settings, but could not find a way to work around this problem including altering the font size.

[image: chart1]

The report has a parent and a subreport. The chart is in the subreport. If it's helpful here are the rdls
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29851290/Sector%20Allocation.rdl
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29851290/SectorAllocationSubreport.rdl

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. The software vendor had placed custom code in the series label properties that was actually sizing the text based on the corresponding pie chart size. So the bigger the pie slice, the more the label was being cut off. I removed this code in the expression editor and used a static value for the property of the pie slices (classificationmembername) and now the text is not being cut off.